# Сохранить проект Python

Tags: python

Подскажите, как нужно сохранять программу, написаную на питоне, чтобы её могли юзать другие пользователи. Как сохраняется проект, в общем, не могу даже правильно сформулировать предложение, надеюсь, меня поняли.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри в сторону [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze).

Но все же, ИМХО лучше установить python на той машине, где будет исполняться твоя программа.

Answer (score 2):

Формулировка немного непонятна.

Если нужно упаковать программу в исполняемый файл, то для windows есть py2exe, например, но он только для python 2.7. Для linux можно собрать свой пакет.

Если надо поделиться исходным кодом, то надо смотреть в сторону систем контроля версий, таких как git, mercurial, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Советую открыть для себя git. А для того, чтобы делиться - github. Если планируется использовать закрытые репозитории, то можно посмотреть на bitbucket.

Comment: как я понял, автор имеет ввиду что-то типа exe файла, который можно передать пользователям, а не программистам

Comment: Вот вот , верно. как ехе использовать другим пользователям

Answer (score 0):

для Windows: [cx_Freeze](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/program-compilation-with-cx-freeze.html), [PyInstaller](https://edunow.su/site/content/python-pyinstaller-no-py2exe), py2exe.
для Linux тот же PyInstaller.
для Mac  - Py2app.

есть мнение, что PyInstaller получше..